# Python Pandas make dict as cell values instead of expanding into new columns

Tags: python, pandas

lets say i have following dict like below:

```
 {1: {2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]},
 4: {2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}
```

the closest attempt i make would make the 2017 and 2016 change into different column like this :

```
key 2016                                  2017

1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

what i wanted is more like this :

```
key value

1   {2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}}    
4   {2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
```

Comment: But why? You typically want to avoid holding dict or list objects in a `DataFrame`

Comment: IIRC, it should be as simple as `{1: {2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}`->`{1: [{2017: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}]`

Comment: @ALollz its something that needed on backend side for using elasticsearch

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(your_dictionary).T.apply(dict,1)

df
>>1    {2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2017: [...
  4    {2016: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2017: [...
```

Answer (score 0):

For now i can do it with list comprehension like this

```
pd.DataFrame([{'key':key,'value':value} for key,value in dict_year.items()])
```

another answer would be appreciated since i need to compare the resource and time used since i doing this with very large data